# Enumerate all properties in Mozilla JSAPI

Tags: javascript, mozilla, jsapi

I want to programmatically list all properties of JS object from C++ code (I am using Mozilla's JSAPI). I know I can go up the prototype chain with `JS_GetPrototype`, then enumerate each object's own properties with `JS_Enumerate`. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is. The code implementing property enumeration for JavaScript (function `js_ValueToIterator()`) uses highly optimized iterators. I don't see these iterators being made accessible to JSAPI anywhere.